# Error calling acf

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to call the acf (correlation) function. Here is part of my code:

```
RowCount <- 100
ColCount <- 2

AMatrix <- matrix(NA_integer_, nrow = RowCount, ncol = ColCount, byrow = FALSE)

AMatrix[,1] <- as.integer(seq.int(from = RowCount, to = 1, by = -1))
AMatrix[,2] <- as.integer(seq.int(from = 1, to = RowCount, by = 1))

# Column 1 is randomized, Column 2 stays the same
AMatrix[,1] <- sample.int(AMatrix[,1])

var(AMatrix)

CorData <- acf(x = AMatrix, type="correlation", plot = FALSE)
```

The call to the "var" function works.

When I call the acf function, I receive this error message:
"Error in acf(x = AMatrix, type = "correlation", plot = FALSE) : 
  object 'C_acf' not found".

I am receiving this error in both RStudio, and the 64-bit RGui.

Could it be that I am missing a library() or require() call? I doubt it.

Any assistance/pointers very much appreciated.

Richard

Comment: Restart your R session.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Very much appreciated! Now I'm going to learn about 'Session' -> 'Restart R', and how that is different from restarting RStudio.